# Atualizar dados no JSON com Vue.js

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

Tenho um pequeno JSON chamado "users"

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Arthur",
    "data": "1998-11-22",
    "email": "arthur@gmail.com",
    "departamento": "Vendas"
  }
]
```

E outro JSON chamado "departamentos"

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "departamento": "Vendas",
    "descricao": "O vendedor funciona como uma ligação da organização com o seu cliente."
  }
]
```

Quando vou adicionar um novo usuário tem um `<select>` mostrando todos os departamentos, eu puxo esses departamentos diretamente do JSON, Abaixo está minha function de Alteração

```
update(form){
        return axios.put('http://localhost:3000/departamentos/' + form.id , {
           departamento: this.form.departamento,
           descricao: this.form.descricao
        }).then(res => {
            this.load()
            this.form.id = ''
            this.form.departamento = ''
            this.form.descricao = ''
            this.updateSubmit = false
            alert("Departamento alterado");
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    }
```

---

Eu consigo alterar o "departamento" do JSON "departamentos" normalmente. O problema é no JSON "users". O users.departamento, ele não é atualizado. De forma resumida, eu adiciono um usuario com departamento Vendas, altero o nome do departamento para RH e o departamento do usuario continua Vendas
Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: `Consigo alterar o departamento normalmente e aparece certinho no JSON, o problema é no usuario, o departamento não é atualizado no JSON! ` Não entendi.

Comment: Eu consigo alterar o "departamento" do JSON "departamentos" normalmente.

O problema é no JSON "users". O users.departamento, ele não é atualizado.

Comment: Tenho 2 JSON's, o "departamentos" e o "users"
Quando altero o "departamentos.departamento" não é alterado no "users.departamento"
Foi oq eu quis dizer...

Comment: De forma resumida, eu adiciono um usuario com departamento Vendas, altero o nome do departamento para RH e o departamento do usuario continua Vendas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Vue não faz deep watch das variáveis. Em outras palavras, seu `arrayDeUsers` foi assinalado uma única vez e a propriedade de um objeto no indice dele foi alterada (`arrayDeUsers[indice].departamento`) e isso não faz com que o Vue saiba que tem que atualizar aquele pedaço de HTML.

Minha sugestão, pelo que você forneceu de código, crie uma variável computada e retorna nele algo +- assim `return usuarios.map(usuario => usuario.departamento)`;

Assim, toda vez que vc alterar o departamento ele irá refletir na tela.

Comment: Muito bom saber disso, obrigado